# $\ker S$ is not contained in $\ker T$ implies $\dim \Im T \ge 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, transformation

Let $T,S:V\rightarrow W$.where $V$ is a finite vector space above $F$ and $W$ is one-dimensional vector-space above $F$ ($\dim W = 1$).

It is given that $\ker S$ isn't contained in $\ker T$. Why is implying that $T \ne 0$ and hence, $\Im T = W$ ($ \dim \Im T= 1 $)?

Comment: Can you see $(T = 0) \iff (\ker T = V)$?

Comment: Yes, I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the rank-nullity theorem:

$$\dim V=\dim\ker T+\dim\operatorname{im} T$$
Clearly if $T=0$ then $\ker T=V$ and then $\ker S\subset \ker T$ which contradicts the hypothesis. Hence $T\ne0$ and then $\dim \ker T=\dim V-1$ and $\dim \operatorname{im} T=1$ which means that $\operatorname{im} T=W$.

Comment: Oh right right.. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't see why rank-nullity has to get involved; it comes directly from the definition of kernel. If $T = 0$, then $\forall x \in V$, $T(x) = 0$. Therefore, $V \subseteq \ker T$, and since the reverse containment is obvious, $\ker T = V$. Once you have that, the only thing $\mathrm{im} \, T$ can be is $W$ (since the only subspaces of a dimension $1$ subspace are itself and zero, which is a very brief proof).